# Django PostgreSQL ArrayField does not work

Tags: python, django

I have just switched to PostegreSQL. Now whenever I add the following code to my Custom User Model, the database is broken, no new values are added to the database, for example during registration

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    code = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='code',)

    #part that breaks the databse:
     ip_addresses = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(blank=True), default=list)
```

From the moment also no more migrations are recognized.
Or I get something like this

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "ip_addresses" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ER COLUMN "ip_addresses" TYPE varchar(15)[] USING "ip_addres...
```

What error I get is 50 50 chance but atleast the first error is always here.

I also tried this which did not work either

```
ip_addresses = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=15), default=list)
```